# Need to do fuzzy matching on an array from a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to complete a homework assignment, I need to match a combination of 5 items in an array against a file list.

```
"Orange, banana, cat, apple, strings"
```

I have a file that has all these words, and a combination of them

```
ex: 
1: Orange
2: Banana
3: CatBanana
```

I need to count all of these individually

```
`ex: Orange=1, Banana=1 CatBanana=1`
```

Comment: Please add some additional details on what kind of file are you reading from the sample code you tried

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to find how many times your list of words appears in your file (line-by-line)?

```
w = ['some', 'list', 'of', 'words']
r = dict.fromkeys(w,0)  # used to store values
filename = 'file.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:  # open file
    lines = f.readlines()  # file to list
    for string in lines:
        for word in w:
            if word in string:
                r[word] += 1  # update
print(r)
```

If not then I would check this post out: [Read words from file into dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970421/read-words-from-file-into-dictionary)

**EDIT:**

Just format the array of words to match the ones you're trying to look for or lowercase everything so formatting doesn't get in the way (like *RootTwo* did). I believe you're trying to also compare the file to the array so:

```
# fix formatting for comparison.
format_this = "Orange, banana, cat, apple, strings"  # lowercase if necessary
separate = format_this.split(', ')  # ['Orange', 'banana', 'cat', 'apple', 'strings']
compare = [word.capitalize() for word in separate]  # ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Cat', 'Apple', 'Strings']

# set file to dict.
filename = 'file.txt'
lines = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:  # open file
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in lines]  # clean up, lowercase if necessary
r = dict.fromkeys(lines,0)  # {'Orange': 0, 'Banana': 0, 'CatBanana': 0}

# compare and record.
for key in r:
    for word in compare:
        if word in key:  # match found
            r[key] += 1  # update value
            break  # stop and move on once match found, remove if necessary
print(r)  # {'Orange': 1, 'Banana': 1, 'CatBanana': 1}
```

Comment: That's awesome! thank you!

but it seems to miss some words from the test file.

Answer (score 0):

#### str.count()

use `str.count(s)` to count how many times s occurs in str:

```
datafile = 'data.txt'

items = "Orange banana cat apple strings".lower().split()
counts = dict.fromkeys(items, 0)

with open(datafile, 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.lower()

        for item in items:
            counts[item] += line.count(item)

print(counts)
```